# Applescript .app always gives -1708

Tags: bash, applescript, runtime-error

I am making a basic pingtest to stretch my knowledge of bash and Applescript, so I made this:

```
on run argv
try
    if (count argv) is less than 1 or (count argv) is greater than 1 then
        set IP_address to ""
        set dialog_1 to display dialog "Enter IP Address:" default answer "" with title "Ping"
        set the IP_address to the text returned of dialog_1
        try
            set ping to (do shell script "ping -c 2 " & IP_address)
            display dialog "Connection Successful." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
            return 1
        on error
            --if we get here, the ping failed
            display dialog "Conection failed. Host is down" buttons {"Darn"} default button 1
            return 0
        end try
    end if
    if (count argv) = 1 then
        set IP_address to item 1 of argv
        try
            set ping to (do shell script "ping -c 2 " & IP_address)
            return 1
        on error
            -- if we get here, the ping failed
            return 0
        end try
    end if
on error error_message number error_number
    if (error_number) is not equal to -128 then
        display alert ("An error has occured!") message error_message & (" Error number ") & error_number & "."
    end if

    return error_number
end try
```

end run

(I couldn't get the end run inside the code snippet)

And in bash I made this:

!/bin/bash
currentDir=`pwd`
Success=`$currentDir/$1/Contents/MacOS/applet $2`
echo $Success

(I couldn't get any of that inside a code snippet)

When I run just the AppleScript, in the editor it works fine, but the .app and bash versions give me the -1708 error. I have narrowed the problem down to this: `if (count argv) is less than 1 or (count argv) is greater than 1 then`

What could I do to fix this, or even just make my code neater?

Thanks

EDIT(1): I want my program to run a GUI version if it's not provided any arguments, and when it is passed arguments, I want it to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to an AppleScript directly from bash like this:

```
--AppleScript named myScript.scpt
    on run {argv}
        beep argv
    end run
```

Command:

```
osascript -e 'run script "/Users/user1781742/Desktop/myScipt.scpt" with parameters {2}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want my program to run a GUI version if it's not provided any arguments, and when it is passed arguments, I want it to run in the background.
(Will add to OP)